# JavaScript versus google flash component... possible?

Tags: javascript, flash

I'm in JavasSript, but not in Flash, so maybe you can help me with this one. 
I have embed some audio on a page using the google component, as here :

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.google.com/reader/ui/3247397568-audio-player.swf?audioUrl=MP3_FILE_URL" width="400" height="27" allowscriptaccess="never" quality="best" bgcolor="#ffffff" wmode="window" flashvars="playerMode=embedded" />
```

What I want to do (if it's possible), is to "query" the component to know where in time it is, and do some event depending on timeline. Is it possible using only JavaScript ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This will depend entirely on whether the flash component provides an external api.  In general, it's possible to allow javascript to access a flash component.  However, it has to be explicitly designed into the flash component.

I'd check to see if there are any docs from google about using this flash component.  I'd also check to see where it's embeded to see if any javascript on the page is accessing it.

Lastly, if you look at the embed, it seems it has an attribute allowscriptaccess="never".  That seems relevant:)

Comment: that's what I thought after reading Jon Cram answer's answer. And yes, just after sending the question I noticed the "allowscriptaccess"... I have to find a place on how deal with the scriptaccess="always/yes"... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adobe provide a JavaScript API for interacting with Flash:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/javascript_api.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [swfobject javascript library](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)